# How to dynamically add plots (lines/traces) from different sources/datasets to a plotly object in R (Shiny)?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to dynamically add data to a plotly object. The new data comes from different datasets that might have different lengths. Assume the following data:

Assume df1 is:

```
date|value
1/1/2020|1
2/1/2020|23
...
10/1/2020|40
```

I can easily plot this like:

```
plot_ly (df1, x = ~date, y = ~value, mode = 'lines', type = 'scatter', name = 'trace 0')
```

However, I have a **select box** that user can interactively select any other dataset with the same **column names** but different lengths, assume the user picks df2:

```
date|value
1/1/2019|1
2/1/201|24
... 
10/1/2020|43
```

How can I add the newly selected dataset to the previous plot, considering the same column names but different lengths?

The user might continue this process and add more datasets to the plot interactively.

Cheers

Comment: Do you want to append the data to the existing trace, replace the data of the existing trace or add a trace? [This](https://community.plotly.com/t/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-update-a-graph-with-new-data/639/6?u=ismirsehregal) might be of interest.

Comment: I want to append, overlay them all in one plot.

Comment: Were you able to solve this now?

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks for the help, I solved that part, but I have a new issue now. I used 'PlotProxyInvoke ('addTraces', ...)' and it works for adding traces, but my highlight function does not work now. I will explain this as a new answer to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to use [extendTraces](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyextendtraces) along with `plotlyProxy`, which once was online [here](https://plot.ly/r/streaming/#streaming-in-r):

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

rand <- function() {
  runif(1, min=1, max=9)
}

ui <- fluidPage(      
  headerPanel(h1("Streaming in Plotly: Multiple Traces", align = "center")),
  br(),
  div(actionButton("button", "Extend Traces"), align = "center"),
  br(),
  div(plotlyOutput("plot"), id='graph')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  p <- plot_ly(
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines'
  ) %>%
    add_trace(
      y = c(rand(),rand(),rand()),
      line = list(
        color = '#25FEFD',
        width = 3
      )
    ) %>%
    add_trace(
      y = c(rand(),rand(),rand()),
      line = list(
        color = '#636EFA',
        width = 3
      )
    ) %>%
    layout(
      yaxis = list(range = c(0,10))
    )
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(p)
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    while(TRUE){
      Sys.sleep(1)
      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(rand()), list(rand()))), list(1,2))
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip @ismirsehregal, I fixed the code this way:

Step 1: I initialized the plot with an empty layout:

```
output$my_plot <- renderPlotly ({
       plot_ly (mode = 'lines') %>%
            layout(showlegend = TRUE) 
    })
```

Step 2: I created a button for the user to add traces from a new selected dataset using 'plotlyProxy' and 'plotlyProxyInvoke' functions:

```
observeEvent (input$add_trace, {

        plotlyProxy("my_plot", session) %>%
          plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", list (x = selected_dataset$date, y = selected_dataset$close,  mode = 'lines', type = 'scatter') 
        
        })
```